# Use column value in rowsBetween Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sum

```py
spec = Window. \
    partitionBy("material_id"). \
    orderBy("date"). \
    rowsBetween( Window.currentRow, 3)

rop.withColumn("lt_demand", f.sum("expected_demand").over(spec)).show()
```

This will get me the sum of expected demand of the current row and the `3` next rows, my question is, I want to use the value of `avg_lt` column instead of the `3`.

[image]

so if `avg_lt` is `8`, then I will have `lt_demand` = sum of expected demand of the next `8` rows.

Comment: input, expected output in text format are recommended in SO, images are not recommended..!

Comment: where is `date` coming from ?

Comment: the arguments for rowsbetween are constants, you can't use a column value.

Answer (score 0):

```
rowsBetween( Window.currentRow,int(rop.select('avg_lt').collect()[Window.currentRow][0])))
```

worked perfectly